# sas ssd in raid or nvme in storage pool

Tags: raid, storage, hp, storage-spaces

this may have been asked several times but till now I can't find a decent answer
I am configuring a server for a hyper-v setup with around 5 VM

look for the best solution performance and redundancy-wise

knowing that there is no raid for nvme in HP DL380 yet (no vROC) , I was thinking about these 2 options

option 1 :
6 x sas ssd multi use in raid 5 or 10 per example

option 2

2 x sas ssd in raid 1 ( for the boot drive ) + 4 nvme ssd in storage spaces in server 2019 ( i am not sure about fault tolerance like mirroring performance)

VM include a big SQL server , domain controller and a file server but the server should stay efficient for around 5 years

What do you advise ?

Answer (score 0):

The RAID-5 configuration has been discouraged for years for use in production due to the serious problems it has, both for limitations and risks when replacing a failed device.

Wanting to use a Windows machine for this job a choice I would recommend is an LSI 9271 with a 2cm fan screwed on (the chipset tends to overheat), and RAID-1 configuration.
Big no-no for RAID-5, and no-no for 10

In case of problems, the simpler the RAID configuration, the easier it is to fix it.

Comment: So sas ssd in raid 1 is the best configuration?

Comment: For me SATA SSDs in RAID1 is the best configuration for Windows machines, followed by SAS SSDs in RAID1 (for Windows). It is much, much easier to maintain a SATA drive than a SAS. Another tip: if you use SAS controllers you must have AT LEAST two, one on the production machine, a second on an emergency PC, flashed with the same firmware version. This will allow you to easily mount a degraded RAID array if needed